# Is this equivalent to any famous NP-complete problem?

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs, np-complete

Given the following problem.

> Given an $n\times n$ matrix $A := \{a_{ij}\}$. Find an $n\times n$ matrix $X := \{x_{ij}\}$, where $x_{ij} \in \{-1, 1\}$ for $i, j \in [n]$, that minimizes the following expression. $$\sum_{i,j}a_{ij}x_{ij} - \sum_{|i-k|+|j-l|=1} x_{ij}x_{kl}$$

My question is: is this problem equivalent to any "famous" NP-complete problem? I was able to find a number of similar minimization questions for MAXCUT-type tasks or for Ising model formulations in physics, but never this particular one.

Edit for clarification - by minimization here I meant finding a set of optimal $x_{ij}$ (output) given a certain set of $a_{ij}$ (input).

To give a concrete example: let $A$ be equal to $\begin{vmatrix}3 & 1 \\-1 & -2 \end{vmatrix}$. We want to find a matrix $\{x_{ij}\}$ that would minimize the following expression:

$3x_{11} + x_{12} -x_{21} - 2x_{22} - x_{11}x_{12} - x_{11}x_{21}- x_{12}x_{22}- x_{21}x_{22}$.

Since $x_{ij}$ can only be equal to +1 or -1, for this small $n = 2$ case we can scan through all sixteen possibilities to find the solution: $x_{11} = x_{12} = -1$, $x_{21} = x_{22} = 1$.

Comment: Should there be coefficients in second sum also?

Comment: A minor comment on presentation: It's common to find letters like $x,y,z$ used for variables (that can be chosen freely) and letters like $a,b,c$ used for constants (that are part of the input), so it is a tiny bit confusing to see that convention reversed here.

Comment: @Szymon Stankiewicz No, that's the point. The second sum has no coefficients, or coefficients equal to 1 everywhere.

Comment: @ D.W. I'm sorry, I'm not very familiar with CS conventions. But I intended here for $x$ to be variables which can be equal to -1 or 1 only, whereas $a$ are maybe not constants but parameters of the problem? In any case, we minimize by finding an optimal set of $x_{ij}$ for a given set of $a_{ij}$.

Comment: I'm confused.  What are the inputs to the algorithm, and what do you want the algorithm to output?  Can you edit to clarify?

Comment: @ D.W. I'll admit that "chosen freely" was a poor choice of words. Hopefully it's clearer now.

Comment: Could you please give an example? For example, if you choose $x_{11},x_{12}, x_{14},x_{21}$, then what is $\sum_{neighbors}x_{ij}x_{kl}$?

Comment: @xskxzr For $x_{11}$ the sum $\sum_{neighbors} x_{ij}x_{kl} = x_{11}(x_{12} + x_{21})$. For $x_{12}$ the sum $\sum_{neighbors} x_{ij}x_{kl} = x_{12}(x_{11} + x_{13} + x_{22})$. For $x_{14}$ the sum $\sum_{neighbors} x_{ij}x_{kl} = x_{14}(x_{13} + x_{15} + x_{24})$. For $x_{21}$ the sum $\sum_{neighbors} x_{ij}x_{kl} = x_{21}(x_{11} + x_{31} + x_{22})$. This is of course assuming $n > 4$.

Comment: What if $x_{11},x_{12},x_{14},x_{21}$ are **all** chosen? What is the sum then?

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by choosing all of them? The second sum contains every possible pair of direct neighbors, so we could write $\sum_{all-neighbors} = \sum_{neighbors-of-x-{11}} + \sum_{neighbors-of-x-{12}} + ... + \sum_{neighbors-of-x-{21}} + ...$. I have now added a small clarification to the post to better indicate it.

Comment: You said "finding a set of optimal $x_{ij}$", doesn't it mean choosing a subset among $x_{ij}$'s? I suggest adding an concret example to your question, clealy desribing the input and the output.